# Drag/Slide div inside overflow:hidden container on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery, webkit, draggable, drag

I am creating a wepapp, that has a horizontal menu. The menu is limited to 320px and has overflow set to hidden. Inside the links are wrapped in a div which has a width set to it. The list overflows on the x axis. I have applied a jquery plugin called OverScroll so you can drag this list left and right to reveal the hidden menu items.

It works great on a desktop browser but I am having difficulty on getting this to work on the iphone.

I have set up a demo at www.irfanyasin.com/iphone/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from general usability issues (will people know it's slidable? I could see how this can be annoying if you use that menu often and have to slide it a lot), dragging doesn't work on most touch interfaces. You could try adding left and right buttons that scroll the menu when they click them maybe?

Also your demo doesn't work in Chrome on my desktop. Is the menu supposed to slide? It won't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Litso, I actually saw a very similar implementation on the Mashable app and the old Facebook iPhone site also used to use this effect.

I have tested it on chrome and it did work if you hold down and drag on the horizontal menu it should drag left and right